# How to access NSFetchRequest results in Swift 3?

Tags: core-data, swift3

Let's say that I want to fetch some NSManagedObjects from Core Data and enumerate all the results:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Chapter", in: context)
request.entity = entityDesc
do
{
    let result = try context.execute(request)
}
catch
{
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Now I have a NSPersistentStoreResult object as result of the query, but I don't know what to do with it. The class documentation is empty:

[image]

How am I supposed to retrieve the managed objects returned by the fetch request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `fetch` method of a `NSManagedObjectContext`

First create the fetch request which can be general or specific:

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<YourObject> = YourObject.fetchRequest

let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = YourObject.fetchRequest
```

Then fetch it:

```
let results = context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch easily:

Suppose you have Photo Entity

```
let request:NSFetchRequest<Photo> = Photo.fetchRequest()
/*        OR
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Photo")
 */
do {
    photos = try coreDataStack.context.fetch(request) as [Photo]
    collectionVIew.reloadData()
    print(photos?.count ?? "No Photo found")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error in fetch :\(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the header for `NSManagedObjectContext`, the `execute()` method that you're calling from Swift is intended for requests that affect only the underlying persistent store without being processed by the context itself. This doesn't make much sense for a fetch request, because it's only purpose is to bring things from a persistent store into a context.

Here's the relevant snippet from the `NSManagedContext` header file from Core Data:

> ```
> // Method to pass a request to the store without affecting the contents of the managed object context.
> // Will return an NSPersistentStoreResult which may contain additional information about the result of the action
> // (ie a batch update result may contain the object IDs of the objects that were modified during the update).
> // A request may succeed in some stores and fail in others. In this case, the error will contain information
> // about each individual store failure.
> // Will always reject NSSaveChangesRequests.
> - (nullable __kindof NSPersistentStoreResult *)executeRequest:(NSPersistentStoreRequest*)request error:(NSError **)error API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.10),ios(8.0));
> ```